# How to modify auto populate field value?

Tags: nodes, entities, ajax

I m Stuck in two situation where I have to modify value of one field depending on another field selection.

1. First situation is like I have two field

   - Region (Node reference) - the widget type is autocomplete
   - Subregion (Node reference) - the widget type is autocomplete

     On select of region, subregion value should be populate. 
     Behavior should be same like country and state.
2. Second situation is like in same form I have another two field

   - Date field
   - Event - widget type is auto complete

     On select of date, events on that date should be populate.

Both are almost similar situation. I haven't found any solution for both above situation. How can I do this. Please anyone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Check `ajax_example_dependent_dropdown()` function in [AJAX Example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example%21ajax_example.module/7.x-1.x) module available as sub-module of [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module.